# So, we can use many different structures for 1 set of meaning of a word, right?

Tags: word-usage, complementation

Ok, for example, look at the word "**spend**" in the dictionary. The word has many meanings & each meaning has many different structures.

> [transitive] to use time for a particular purpose; to pass time [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/spend_1?q=spend)

**spend something + adv./prep.** 
*We spent the weekend in Paris.*

**spend something on something.** *How long did you spend on your homework?*

**spend something doing something.** *I spend too much time watching television.*

**spend something in doing something.** *Most of her life was spent in caring for others.*

So, my question is that:

If we can say "*I spent a lot of time on my homework*", then can we say:

-"*I spent a lot of time doing my homework*"

-"*I spent a lot of time in doing my homework*"

If we can say "*I spent too much time watching television*", then can we say:

-"*I spent too much time on television*"

-"*I spent too much time in watching television*"

If we can say "*She spent most of her life in caring for others*", then can we say:

-"*She spent most of her life caring for others*"

Comment: Yes, one verb can have several different ways of taking complements ("verb complementation"). Different verbs and different senses of a verb may differ in their "patterns of verb complemenation".

Comment: The gist of what you're saying is correct. As a footnote, though, I would not say, "I spent too much time **in** watching television," (but I might say, "I spent too much time **sitting in front of the** television").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I spent a lot of time doing my homework.
>   I spent a lot of time in doing my homework.

I would say these two are correct, though the first is probably used more.

> She spent most of her life caring for others.

Is a perfect sentence.

> I spent too much time on television.
>   I spent too much time in watching television.

The first sentence could be mean you received overexposure on television versus other media. The second sentence sounds awkward, better would be:

> I spent too much time watching television.

I think this may be because **on television** has a specific meaning.
However, we usually *spend* ***on*** *things*.

Comment: "**spend time in watching television**" returns 7 results in Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spent+too+much+time+in+watching+television.%22&oq=%22spent+too+much+time+in+watching+television.%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.967j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=%22spend+time+in+watching+television%22

Comment: "**spend time on watching television**" returns 10   
"**Spend time watching television**" returns ~16,300